# Population Growth: Adding rows to data based on groupings by age group (adding new "people")

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

New to python**

I currently have a base population which I am aging and regrouping by age categories. What I would like to do is add "new" people and remove people from this base population in addition to aging them.

For example: I have a list of ages: 22, 25,27,30,35,38...(etc)
and have sorted into bins and counted:

```sh
<20 0
20 to 24 12
25 to 29 60
30 to 34 138
35 to 40 242
```

I also have a "change" vector which by age group has additions or subtractions 
so `[0,12,-4,3,-2]`

so the new category counts would be

```sh
<20 0
20 to 24 24
25 to 29 56
30 to 34 141
35 to 40 240
```

What I would like to do is map these changes back to the original data set to get the new count. So actually add 12 people between the ages of 20-24(randomly preferably), and subtract 4 rows from the original data set randomly between ages 30 to 34

The plan would be that this would happen within a loop, and each year, the data set would get aged, and then additions or subtractions would be done, and then new count.

Currently I am able to loop through aging the population and create a count for each year as well as pull out the change vector for each year, but I am uncertain how to add people to my population using the change vector amounts so that they are added or subtracted within a specific age range.

This is what I have so far..

```py
for i in range(years):
    year=year+1
    ages=ages+1
    bins=pd.cut(ages.AGE,[0,20,24,29,34,39,44,49,54,59,64,69,150],labels=['<20','20 to 24','25 to 29','30 to 34','35 to 39', '40 to 45','45 to 49','50 to 54','55 to 59','60 to 64','65 to 69','>=70'],include_lowest=True)
    count=ages.groupby(bins)['AGE'].agg('count')
    change=np.array(change_vecs[change_vecs.columns[i]])
```

output would be a new population for each year, built off of the original population. Where people are represented by their age.